# Office 365 license for Ipad

Tags: office-365

I bought a new IPad, I want to subscribe to office 365,

What's the required license ? , Is there a trial period with all features?

Any link of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Office 365 for 1 month free  check this [link](https://products.office.com/en-us/try)

There are 2 famous types of licenses For Home and For Business. I recommend you can start from [Office365 Home](https://products.office.com/en-us/try)

**Office 365 Home trial includes**

- Fully installed Office 2016 versions of Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Outlook, and more.
- Installation on up to 5 PCs or Macs.
- Office mobile apps on up to 5 tablets and 5 phones.
- 1 TB of OneDrive cloud storage per user, for up to 5 users.

This [link](https://products.office.com/en-us/compare-all-microsoft-office-products?tab=1&ms.opt_eid=1315838) will give you more detailed and updates.

Comment: thank you for your answer, How i can pay on IPad ? can i unsubscribe during the trail period ?

Comment: You can pay from Credit Card. Since it's monthly subscription, you can unsubscribe any time during trial.

Comment: is it required to provide the credit card in trail period ?

Comment: For the trial, I think Credit card is not required.

Comment: i tried a trail, it requires a credit card :((

Comment: They will not charge you in trial period.